# why isn't my OCaml babbage program working?

Tags: ocaml

**code:**

```ml
let babbage = 
  let n = read_int in
  let current = ref n in
  let square = ref !current in
  let mul = !current * !current in
  while ((square := mul) mod 1000000 != 269696) && (!square < max_int) do
          current := !current + 1;
  done;
  if(!square > max_int) then
    print_string "Condition not satisfied before max_int reached."
  else print_string "The smallest number whose square ends in 269696 is"; !square
```

**the error:**

```
let mul = !current * !current in
  Error: This expression has type unit -> int
         but an expression was expected of type int
         Hint: Did you forget to provide `()' as argument?
```

still learning but I wanted to really know what is wrong with it

**EDIT #1:** this is a practice exercise, and the type that is asked is `unit -> int` and it is given the function as `let babbage () =`

Answer (score 5):

The error message gives you quite a good hint, but you have to follow a few assignment to find the cause.

`square` is initially given the value (and type) of `current`, which is initially given the value of `n`, which is initially given the value of `read_int`.

`read_int` is a function `unit -> int`, therefore `n` will also have the type `unit -> int`, and so will `current` and `square`.

If you apply the hint given in the error message to `read_int`, the problem should be fixed. (It's not your only problem though, but that's out of scope for this question.)

Comment: Good catch! As a general rule, when the type system is telling you something that makes no sense, it can often help to add type annotations to your `let` clauses with the types you *expect* variables to have. This will help you and the compiler narrow down where the disagreement originated.

Comment: that makes sense, with parenthesis it will become just int right? what it is currently saying is that n is a read_int, a function that returns a int, or not?

Comment: Correct. `read_int` is a function that takes an argument of type `unit`, whose only value is `()`, and returns a value of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum, this problem does not require imperative programming at all. We can solve it readily using recursion. We can write a function `babbage` which takes an `int` and increments it up until it finds a number whose square ends in `269696`.

```
let rec babbage n =
  let max = 
    Int.max_int 
    |> float_of_int 
    |> sqrt 
    |> int_of_float  
  in
  let square = n * n in
  if n > max then None
  else if square mod 1_000_000 = 269696 then Some n
  else babbage (n + 1)
```

This will return `int option` which you can then pattern match on to determine if a number was found or not.

```
let () =
  let n = read_int () in
  match babbage n with
  | None -> 
     print_endline "Condition not satisfied before max_int reached."
  | Some n' -> 
     Printf.printf 
       "The smallest number greater than %d whose square ends in 269696 is %d.\n" 
       n n'
```

Note: the expression using `|>` is equivalent to:

```
int_of_float (sqrt (float_of_int Int.max_int))
```

---

If `babbage` must have the type `unit -> int` then we can put the logic in the above `babbage` function into a locally scoped function let's call it `babbage'` and call that function to do the heavy lifting.

```
let babbage () =
  let rec babbage' n =
    let max = 
      Int.max_int 
      |> float_of_int 
      |> sqrt 
      |> int_of_float  
    in
    let square = n * n in
    if n > max then None
    else if square mod 1_000_000 = 269696 then Some n
    else babbage' (n + 1)
  in
  let n = read_int () in
  ...
```

Now, if `babbage` *must* return `int`, how do we handle the situation where it *doesn't* return an int? In `babbage'` I handled that with the `option` type, but this new one can't return that, so the only options are either to return a nonsense value like `-1` or to raise an exception (the existing standard library `Not_found` exception would seem a logical choice).

```
let babbage () =
  let rec babbage' n =
    let max = 
      Int.max_int 
      |> float_of_int 
      |> sqrt 
      |> int_of_float  
    in
    let square = n * n in
    if n > max then None
    else if square mod 1_000_000 = 269696 then Some n
    else babbage' (n + 1)
  in
  let n = read_int () in
  match babbage n with
  | None -> ...
  | Some n' -> ...
```

Completing the code is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Yes, comparing `!square > max_int` would be always false by definition of `max_int`. (If the number is too high, the square will be meaningless (perhaps negative), then an other comparison was needed like the one proposed here.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, because the original code is in C and I didn't discovered all the errors that it had, thank you!

Comment: Just updated the post with some info, as I don't know how to make it ```unit -> int``` with recursion, because doing, for example, ```let babbage () = read_int()``` is giving that type, maybe thats all I need